# Clear text in Selenium Webdriver (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
async setNumberValue(selector,value){
    let el = await this._driver.findElement(By.css(selector));
    el.click();
    let textel = await this._driver.findElement(By.css(selector + ' input'));
    textel.sendKeys(Key.BACK_SPACE);
    textel.sendKeys(Key.BACK_SPACE);
    textel.sendKeys(value);
    textel.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
  }
```

---

The above code works when I backspace twice.
How can I clear all the text before I send values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `textel.clear();`:

```
async setNumberValue(selector,value){
   let el = await this._driver.findElement(By.css(selector));
   el.click();
   let textel = await this._driver.findElement(By.css(selector + ' input'));
   textel.clear();
   textel.sendKeys(value);
   textel.sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
}
```